# How can I check if 2 columns have similar text in pyspark?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, pyspark, string-comparison

Basically, I'm collecting data from 2 tables and comparing them. Some data is coming from an old table and other is coming from a new table. A brief example can be seen below:

| product_id | old_category | new_category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Metal Scraps | Metal Parts |
| 002 | Car Pars | Car Pieces |
| 003 | Plastic Fender | Fender |

Is there any way to compare the columns `old_category` and `new_category` to check how similar they are?

Comment: You can compute fuzzing string matching score using some lib like [thefuzz](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz) or [python-levenshtein](https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/) and then make decision based on that.

Comment: see [`levenshtein`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.levenshtein.html#pyspark-sql-functions-levenshtein) function in pyspark